# Что такое upper_bound и lower_bound в c++ и чем они отличаются

Tags: c++, c, stl

Скажите пожалуйста, что такое `upper_bound` и `lower_bound` в стандартной библиотеке С++ и как они работают.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ну, например, у вас есть **упорядоченная (важно!) последовательность**

```
1 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 7
```

При поиске [`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) для значения 5 это будет итератор (указатель, если концепция итератора для вас нова) на значение 6 - *первое большее значение*.

Соответственно, [`lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) будет указывать на *первое не меньшее* значение - на первое 5.

Например, код

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int a[20] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,9,9,11,11,12,16,20,20,20,20 };

    for(int * p = lower_bound(a,a+20,10);
        p != upper_bound(a,a+20,20); ++p)
        cout << *p << " ";
    cout << endl;

}
```

дает

```
11 11 12 16 20 20 20 20
```

Comment: важно, что пользоваться этими функциями имеет смысль только для сортированных последовательностей